# How many different macOS system default versions of Python should live on Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, anaconda

I am super frustrated by the different versions of Python on my Mac. Is it usual that I have this many different system python versions? I'm wondering how can I manage them efficiently.

```
$ which -a python python2 python2.7 python3 python3.6
/Users/anonymous/anaconda3/bin/python
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2.7
/Users/anonymous/anaconda3/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

`/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python2.7` appear to give the same system version of Python 2.7:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 17 2018, 17:41:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.0.42)] on darwin
```

`/usr/local/bin/python3`, `/usr/local/bin/python3.6` and `/Users/anonymous/anaconda3/bin/python` appear to give the same system version of Python 3.6:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:41:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
```

`/Users/anonymous/anaconda3/bin/python` and `/Users/anonymous/anaconda3/bin/python3` appear to give the same Anaconda version of Python 3.7:

```
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 07:39:16) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
```

So I am wondering are there really several installations of the same version of Python? and is this what it is supposed to be? If not, what should I do to remove the redundancies? Thanks!

Comment: any aside from one inside `usr/bin/` is safe to remove

Comment: Python 3.6.5 is not a version of Python 3.5, and Python 3.7.0 is not a version of Python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

Some of these refer to the same executable. On most systems, `python` is symlinked to either `python2` or `python3` in the same directory and then those are symlinked to a specific binary for that version such as `python2.7` or `python3.7`. As for the ones in the `anaconda3` folder, the user `anonymous` appears to have installed the Anaconda Python distribution in their home directory. Anaconda is standalone, and can be used instead of or addition to the system python typically.  That can be safely deleted if you are not using it for anything.  The python in `/usr/local/bin` was most likely installed via either Homebrew or from source or a binary installer from python.org